# I'm trying to move an object but i want it to leave a trail

Tags: java, swing, animation, jframe, jlabel

So basically it won't leave a trail. I tried to remove super.paint and i've tried to make multiple but it either creates an error or it doesn't. I've gone throught it atleast 10 times which is why i went here. Thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Grafik extends JPanel {
private int x = 0;

private void moveBall()
{
    x += 1;
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.fillRect(x, 50, 20, 80);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Grafik grafik = new Grafik();

    frame.setSize(700, 800);
    frame.setLocation(300, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(grafik);
    frame.setTitle("Mitt spel");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    while(true)
    {
        grafik.repaint();
        grafik.moveBall();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to make a trail of the ball moving?

Comment: ...............hello?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems/Solutions:

- Swing painting is done in the paintComponent method override, not the paint method.
- Be sure to call the `super's paintComponent method first thing in your own override method, so the JPanel can do house-keeping painting
- Your animation loop should be a Swing Timer, not a while (true) loop as the latter risks running afoul of Swing threading rules
- If you want to create an animation but leave persisting images within the drawing then

  - Either create an ArrayList of objects, perhaps Points, that represent the trail, and in your paintComponent method draw the trail using a for loop that iterates through the ArrayList, or
  - use a BufferedImage as a background image, one that is drawn within the paintComponent method immediately after calling `super.paintComponent(g)` but before drawing the moving sprint. Draw your trail into this BufferedImage by getting a Graphics object out of it, by calling `getGraphics()` on the BufferedImage.